# How to sign a jar for use with Java Web Start

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

Then I did this:

`keytool -genkey -keystore keystore -alias myself`

`jarsigner -keystore keystore <yourApplication>.jar myself`

Which results in this:
[image]

So my question is: How do I sign the jar so it will load?

Answer (score 0):

You will either need a trusted certificate to sign the jar file or you have to add your host to the exception list in the Java Control Panel.
[image]

For more details take a look at this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/new-security-requirements-for-rias-in-7u51-january-2014)